# Angular - only render element attribute if it is defined

Tags: angular

Is it possible in Angular to only render an element attribute if it is defined?

If for example I have a button component

```
export class ButtonComponent {
  /** The name id to be given to the button */
  @Input() id: string;
  /** The name to be given to the button */
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

with a template of

```
<button 
        [id]="id"
        [name]="name"
        >
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

and if I pass it an id but not a name it renders a name attribute with a value of undefined.

```
<button _ngcontent-c1="" id="login" name="undefined">
    Login
</button>
```

Is it possible to not render the name attribute at all if the name input is not supplied like below?

```
<button _ngcontent-c1="" id="login">
    Login
</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of attribute binding angular won't render attribute if we pass `null` or `undefined` to it. So your solution could look like:

```
[attr.name]="name"
```